# "As I said" vs. "Like I said"

Tags: differences, conjunctions, as-like

I was told that saying ***Like I said*** isn't grammatically correct although it is used a lot. That we should use ***As I said*** instead. Is it true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Like I said* is much more informal than *As I said*, but the former isn't ungrammatical. In formal writing you may prefer to use *as*, but in speech or less formal writing *like* is fine.

Comment: However, in formal writing, you aren't _saying_; you're writing. So the more likely outcome is something like _As I pointed out in Chapter 3,_

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, it's interesting to read "Like I said ..." or "Remember when I said ..." in writing; they always mean "Like I wrote ..." or "Remember when I wrote ..." but few writers actually do this.

Comment: Well, part of good writing is taking care not to breach the First Wall and allow the reader to become aware that they're reading symbols off something and not listening to that little voice in their head.

Answer (score 1):

The increasing use of "like" pushing away "as" (expressing comparison) -
especially in colloqial language - may be explained with the fact that the function word "as" has too many meanings.

Comment: I'm convinced it is related rather to foreign speakers - in many languages unlike English "like" and "as" are the same word(and I think "how" as well)