# "Like I said earlier" vs "I have said earlier"?

Tags: phrases, differences

What's the difference in meaning between the two sentences?

1. Like I said earlier
2. I have said earlier

Are they both grammatically correct or wrong?

Comment: Please provide some context.

Comment: Like I said earlier needs a comma following, then that item repeated, maybe restated, or reworded to something similar to (*like*) what you said. I have said earlier needs 'that' said or implied: I have said earlier *that* I am not amused. Either form can be a neutral reminder or can show impatience, as in "Hey, I already told you no (and that remains my answer, but go ahead and keep asking)."

Comment: Your question should have been about _“Like I said earlier” vs “As I have said earlier”?_

Comment: @ΥΣΕΡ26328 How can I say nicely 'That's a rather presumptuous statement'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You can't.

Comment: @ΥΣΕΡ26328 OK; policy on ELU is to use a comment to ask OP to clarify exactly what they mean when there seems to be lack of clarity, not tell them what question they should be asking. At [TimesNow](https://twitter.com/TimesNow/status/881765570118639617), one finds <<
I have said earlier, I am not the PM face of opposition in 2019, neither am I eligible: CM Nitish Kumar >>. Notice the absence of quotation marks. Why can't OP be checking on the acceptability of this? / The as/like question would be a duplicate on ELU.

Comment: I'll add the link to the as/like original: [as I said vs like I said](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140360/as-i-said-vs-like-i-said/140368#140368).

Comment: The first is a pragmatic introductory expression indicating ordering of discourse / recapitulation status. It is not part of the grammar of the matrix sentence (here omitted by OP). Some would prefer 'as' to 'like' here. // The second is synonymous, but would normally be followed by a that-clause rather than an independent clause. Though doubtless using a comma and an independent clause would not raise too many people's hackles in informal conversation.

Answer (score 2):

"Like I said earlier" is conversational in style and distinctly American.  A more common phrasing in the UK and Ireland would be "As I indicated earlier" or even "As indicated earlier", which would be considered more polite since it makes no reference to the speaker/author.  There is no grammatical issue, per se, but the use of "like" (or "as") indicated it is an opinion rather than a fact.  "I have said earlier" is a clear statement.  It would be best used in situations where evidence is being presented to back up your case/argument.

Comment: 'As I said earlier' is a recapitulation marker, used to [help the listener]  tie pieces of dialogue together; it is certainly not a hedging (adding a caveat that the following statement is merely opinion)  device. 'As I said earlier, I've lived here all my life' is a statement of bare fact. And 'Like I said earlier' is merely a variant, less common in the UK.

Comment: Great answer by Kieran by the way, especially the part about it being distinctly American. It's absolutely a very idiomatic saying here. In fact, though the second option could be used in certain contexts if you provided additional information, it would almost always sound strange. "As I said earlier" in @EdwinAshworth recommendation is a much better usage versus the second option in the OP's question. It's the "formal" version of "Like I said earlier" here in the US.